# What is the proper way to pass a hash as a parameter to function call?

Tags: ruby, hash, call, symbols

I have a function:

```
def a p
  p
end
```

and a hash of symbols `:a => :b`. How should I pass it as `a`'s parameter? What are possible ways?

I can use parentheses or the shorter form:

```
a(:a => :b) # => {:a=>:b}
a(a: :b)    # => {:a=>:b}
```

Is there any way to pass this hash as a parameter without setting a variable and using parens? Just omitting them doesn't work.

```
a :a => :b # => SyntaxError: (irb):103: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
a a: :b    # => SyntaxError: (irb):105: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "set a variable".

Comment: @sawa I mean I want to omit the `x = {a: :b}` expression.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, both `a :a => :b` and `a a: :b` should work fine. What's your Ruby version?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? This works just fine on 2.0. I can define the function with `def a(p)...` or `def a p...` or even `def a(*p)...` and they all work the same for your use case.

Comment: `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`